# How to compile libsndfile into a project?

Tags: g++, libsndfile

I am trying to use libsndfile. I am also not very good with g++. The way to install libsndfile seems to be use "make install." I can really do that so I compiled it in a directory.

I was trying to compile the tutorial here:
http://parumi.wordpress.com/2007/12/16/how-to-write-wav-files-in-c-using-libsndfile/

when I try the following:

```
g++  -Isrc/ test.c
```

I get:

```
/tmp/ccq5fhbT.o: In function SndfileHandle::SndfileHandle(char const*, int, int, int, int)':
test.c:(.text._ZN13SndfileHandleC1EPKciiii[SndfileHandle::SndfileHandle(char const*, int, int, int, int)]+0xf4): undefined reference to sf_open'
/tmp/ccq5fhbT.o: In function SndfileHandle::write(float const*, long)':
test.c:(.text._ZN13SndfileHandle5writeEPKfl[SndfileHandle::write(float const*, long)]+0x27): undefined reference to sf_write_float'
/tmp/ccq5fhbT.o: In function SndfileHandle::SNDFILE_ref::~SNDFILE_ref()':
test.c:(.text._ZN13SndfileHandle11SNDFILE_refD1Ev[SndfileHandle::SNDFILE_ref::~SNDFILE_ref()]+0x20): undefined reference to sf_close'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I try to do the following:

```
g++ -lsndfile -Isrc/ test.c
```

I get

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsndfile
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am not sure what switches I need to give g++.

Comment: Give more info about you environment, what GNU/Linux distribution, I think you can install the libs in your system and then compile your program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you configure and install libsndfile with:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local
make
make install
```

you should then set/modify your LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable:

```
export $LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/local/lib
```

and then compile with

```
g++ -I $HOME/local/include -L $HOME/local/lib -lsndfile testsnd.c -o  testsnd
```

Comment: Thanks a lots, is it possible to statically link the library?

Comment: Well, you need a static version of the library and then adding "-static" just before "-lsndfile" should do it.

Answer (score 2):

In GNU/Linux Debian squeeze I have installed the libsndfile1 libraries and the program compiles without problem.

```
# apt-get install libsndfile1-dev
$ g++ -w -o testsnd testsnd.c -lsndfile
```

You need to install the library with you package manager or from source code.

Comment: The problem is I don't have the ability to install packages on that computer

Comment: Why? You don't provide much info, sorry!